# Where the emails are storing in sugarcrm table after configuring email in email module?

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm

I'm running out of time to check the email content in sugarcrm table.

I can see that the following data is stored in message_id column in email_cache table.

> CAOPnfvh4C1hdX4kj15paKvV1Ok8zg-WRzY1mpL+bVJRHGJvvVw@mail.gmail.com

But I'm not able to fetch the body from this encrypted text.

Please let me know how to fetch the body of the emails

Answer (score 1):

Emails are saved in "`email`" table but here only Email metainformation get's saved. If you want to check email data or text, then I am giving you an example, in my case, I need to read incoming email subjects and their attachments from `email` module.

So, I use email table. In `email_text` table you will get email address from and to and description, I need attachments also so I use `parent_id` from email table. 
In note table you will find field `parent_id`, so I found my email attachments in `notes` table.

i think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Amitesh Kumar but here I need to read the body of the email I can able to read the subject from email_cache table.

Comment: Only sent mails are storing in emails table, I need received mails also

Comment: check email_text table